# SQL: Date differences are coming out as negative?

Tags: sql, oracle

My schema looks like

```
select dob, name from student;

DOB        NAME
---------  -------
01-APR-68  rylan
01-APR-70  joshua
01-APR-83  ava
01-APR-76  adalgisa
01-APR-83  zaida
01-APR-83  perry
01-APR-82  aiden
01-APR-75  madison
01-APR-62  zoe
01-APR-72  brendon
01-APR-75  cayden
01-APR-83  hannah
```

When I try to get `age` from date of birth as

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.NAME,
                s.ssn,
                s.address.streetName                                   AS street,
                ( Floor (Months_between(Trunc(sysdate), s.dob) / 12) ) AS age
FROM   student s,
       student s1
WHERE  s.dob = (SELECT Max(DISTINCT dob)
                FROM   student); 


NAME         SSN            STREET                    AGE
-----       --------      ------------                ---
perry       111110003     union square                -69

zaida       111110000     5th street                  -69

hannah      111111111     union square                -69

ava         111118888     5th street                  -69
```

The age is coming as negative, I have no idea why this is happening, can someone please point out the issue with the query?

Thanks

I am using `Oracle` Database

Comment: Your query doesn't make sense.  What is the `where` clause doing?  Why are you doing a self-join?

Comment: How many birthdays can a student have?

Comment: @PM77-1 - Ultimate question

Comment: To find age check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422223/oracle-query-to-calculate-current-age

Comment: I don't get the same results on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b126/5/0

Comment: The self join between `student` does not make any sense and neither does the `distinct` inside the `Max()` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that perhaps you're making this a bit more difficult than it needs to be.  Try:

```
SELECT s.NAME,
       trunc(months_between(Trunc(sysdate), s.dob)/12) AS age
  FROM student s;
```

which produces the result

```
NAME        AGE
rylan       46
joshua      44
ava         31
adalgisa    38
zaida       31
perry       31
aiden       32
madison     39
zoe         52
brendon     42
cayden      39
hannah      31
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b126/3)

Share and enjoy.